# stub method return doesn't work in unit test

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am using [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/reference/) to do unit test.

I have a singleton class `MyManager`:

```
@implementation MyManager
+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

// This is the function I want to stub in my test case
- (NSInteger) getId{
  return [self askBackendToReturn];
}
...
@end
```

In my test case, I want to stub the return of `-(NSInteger) getId:`. I tired the following:

```
id mgrMock = OCMClassMock([MyManager class]);
// read OCMock 3 document, seems the return from OCMClassMock can be either a mocked class or mocked instance. The following line of code is according to its documents "Stubbing methods that create objects" http://ocmock.org/reference/#advanced-topics
OCMStub([[mgrMock alloc] init]).andReturn(mgrMock);

// Now I stub the function to return 1
OCMStub([mgrMock getId]).andReturn(1);

// test it, I still get the real id from backend, WHY?
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
NSInteger mgrId = [sharedManager getId];
```

But when I run, the stub return is not working, it still return the real id. WHY?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's returning the real id is because once `[self alloc]` is called in your implementation, you are dealing with a new instance of `MyManager`. This means that in `[[self alloc] init]` you end up calling `init` on a brand new instance who has no knowledge of the stubbed methods.

If you want to take the approach of stubbing the `MyManager` initialization, you will have to stub both `[mgrMock alloc]` and `[mgrMock init]` to return your mock object.

In this spirit of unit testing, my suggestion is to nix this approach entirely, and instead simply stub `sharedManager` to return `mgrMock`. Your test is related to the singleton's Id, and should assume that initialization is working as expected.